# Why do all websites that I access on Android Emulator are displayed extremely pixelated?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using .NET MAUI to develop web apps. I'm trying to access a server on my localhost. But all pages, even sites like Wikipedia and Pexels are displayed really pixelated:

[image]

I tried install other emulator devices, and it's all the same.

These are the emulator settings:

[image]

Here is some information about my computer:

[image]

I don't have a dedicated VGA. It's an Dell Optiplex 7070.
How to fix this?

Comment: 1) Please describe your hardware (CPU/GPU/memory) and OS (Win/Linux) if anything for future visitors. 2) Have you tried other emulator graphics settings: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#command-gpu